# What kind of a JSON object is this? (Gitlab API), (Python)

Tags: python, json, gitlab

Im accessing the content of a file using GitLab's File Repository API, and all seems to be going fine until I hit one specific file (any text file).

```
{:file_name=>"requirements.txt", :file_path=>"requirements.txt", :size=>30, :encoding=>"base64", :content=>"ImZsYXNrIgoidXdzZ2kiCiJnb2dvc2VjcmV0cyIK", :ref=>"master", :blob_id=>"7f551dddd4fd8931419450fb357bad83d2efbe6a", :commit_id=>"40e161fcb323be28259712a6cf5da8fddfda80e1", :last_commit_id=>"40e161fcb323be28259712a6cf5da8fddfda80e1"}
```

I have never seen colons before a key, and have never seen a '=>' in a JSON object. All other JSON objects returned have been fine. The request being made to the API isn't wrong because a 200 response is being returned.

**What is this??**

Comment: Not JSON is what it is.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/2298 seems relevant.

Comment: Looks like a ruby hash (dictionary).

Comment: Seems like text files are the issue primarily. A possible workaround would be to use Gitlab's Get Raw File from repository, vs Get file from repository

Comment: link is here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an open bug in Gitlab.  See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/2298.

> **What is the current bug behavior?**
>
> Response:
>
> ```
> {:file_path=>"Readme.txt", :branch=>"master"}
> ```
>
> **What is the expected correct behavior?**
>
> Response:
>
> ```
> {"file_name": "Readme.txt", "branch": "master"}
> ```

Comment: Do you know if GitLab uses Ruby for any backend work? That looks exactly like a Ruby hash, and they could be forgetting to convert it to JSON.

Comment: @ChristianDean - It appears so: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/architecture.html#system-layout

Comment: Not sure how I should handle getting content from text files now. This file needs to be a text file

Answer (score 1):

The issue is still opened on gitlab ([issue 2298](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/2298))

I encountered the same problem.
I confirm that only `.txt` files are affected. Files with unknown extensions for Git are not affected (e.g. : `.myFile`, `.unknowExtension` ...)

This can be detected with the `Content-Type` header, set as text/plain when Gitlab sent response in ruby hash.

Here is a simple function to parse ruby hash in PHP.

```
function ruby_hash_decode($ruby)
    {
        if (substr( $ruby, 0, 2 ) === "{:") {

            $ruby = str_replace('{:', '{"', $ruby);

            $ruby = str_replace('", :', '", "', $ruby);

            $ruby = str_replace(', :', ', "', $ruby);

            $ruby = str_replace('=>"', '":"', $ruby);

            $ruby = str_replace('=>', '":', $ruby);

            $ruby = \json_decode($ruby);
        }

        return $ruby;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Ruby hash to Python dict or json converter. Note, the below solution is a quick n' dirty one I made in 2 minutes. You can do much better if you use regex.

```
s = '{:file_path=>"Readme.txt", :branch=>"master"}'
s = s[1:-1]
s = s.split(',')
s = [elem.strip() for elem in s]
s = [subs[1:] for subs in s]
s = [subs.replace('"', '') for subs in s]
my_dict = {elem.split('=>')[0]: elem.split('=>')[1] for elem in s}
```

`my_dict` looks like this now: `{'file_path': 'Readme.txt', 'branch': 'master'}`

Comment: This solution avoids solving the actual problem, where the problem is defined as an issue with Gitlab API. See  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/2298